# Which one is better in javascript if I need to check if the object is available or not. 'in' or typeof obj.key !== "undefined"

Tags: javascript, window, javascript-objects, typeof, navigator

I need to check if a child object is available in a object or not. 
Let the parent object is `window` and child object would be `navigator`.
There could be multiple ways to do it.

1. `'navigator' in window`
2. `typeof window.navigator !== "undefined"`

Which one would be the ideal way to do it.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, you could even do `if ( window.navigator )`, but it's all opinion-based

Comment: I prefer 1, only because it is shorter

Answer (score 1):

If it is an object, The below four methods should have the same time complexity:

```
if('navigator' in window){...}

if(typeof window.navigator !== "undefined"){...}

if(window.navigator){...}

if(window.hasOwnProperty('navigator')){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.In the first way if you check navigator as a variable"

```
if(navigator)
```

and the navigator variable wasn't declared your code will lead to an error. However if you you check it like a parameter of the window such as:

```
if(window.navigator)
```

you won't get an error and your check will result to undefinded => false (since you convert it to boolean inside the "if" statement). It is important to remember that the if statement will also result to false if your variable is null.

2.With the second syntax you check exactly what you mention in your question. 
"I need to check if a child object is available in an object or not."

In conclusion I would recommend the second way for your question.

Comment: First way isn't `if(navigator)` or `if(window.navigator)`. It is `if('navigator' in window)`.

Answer (score 0):

what's your meaning?

you want to check does an object owner or instance of another Object?

```
'navigator' in window different with typeof window.navigator !== "undefined"
```

if you want to check, does navigator in window you'd better use

```
 typeof window.navigator !== "undefined"   //safety
```

and if you want to check instance, you'd better use keywords **instance of**

**pay attention**

you should not use

```
 if (variable) //do something, because it's not safety.
```

Comment: You said, `'navigator' in window`  is different with `typeof window.navigator !== "undefined" `                                       


How is that ?